# Disable RayGun in development

Tags: angular, raygun

I'd like to disable raygun in development.  Any console.logs I have are coming from raygun.umd.js rather than my own javascript files.  I've tried not importing it in my app.module but it's still taking over my console.   It seems that if there's any reference to it anywhere in the application - in a error handling service, for example, the raygun takes over.   The only way I can ensure it won't be active in development is if I go through and individually remove all references to it, which isn't feasible in the long run.  I'd rather there was just a switch that I could disable in development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because, when attached, Raygun will listen for the global error event and therefore creates a stack frame in your stack trace.

Your best bet would simply be to add something akin to:

```
if (!dev)
{
  rg4js('enableCrashReporting', true);
}
```

This should prevent Raygun attaching to that event. It also means they won't get reported at all. How you store the 'dev' value is up to you however.

I hope that helps!